# Twilio: Waiting voice (Say) while the caller is waiting for a response from forwarded number (Dial)

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I struggle with something that seem simple:

**When I receive a call on a twilio phone number, I want to forward the call using `<Dial>`, and while the caller waits, play a message that can also gather user input.**

I managed to forward a call OR to make the caller here the message and gather input but not both in parallel

Here is what I tried:

```js
...
const response = new VoiceResponse()
response.dial('+33611182299')
response.enqueue({
    waitUrl: `https://myapi.com/api/repondeur/wait-msg`,
}, 'support')
...
```

I also tried to set `Dial`in waitUrl, and a lot of different combinations (like changing the order, trying to create a queue...etc) with no success.

Also tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117172/how-to-play-hold-music-when-phone-call-is-waiting-for-an-answer-client-in-twiml?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321365/play-music-while-waiting-an-answer-in-twiml-dial?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it didn't work

Could you point me to the right direction please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and headbanging, here is what I've got:

```js
const inProgressCallsCache = {}


// MAIN WEBHOOK ROUTE
export const answerCallSvc = {
    route: '/answer-call',
    async main(body) {
        const response = new VoiceResponse()

        // First we redirect caller to the waiting url
        response.enqueue({
            waitUrl: url(`/answer-call/wait-msg`),
            method: 'POST',
        }, queueName)

        // Then we call the respondent. When he'll answer
        // the call will be redirected to `url`
        const call = await client.calls
            .create({
                to: telTest,
                from: body.Caller,
                url: url(`/answer-call/call-back`),
                method: 'POST',
                // time while trying to call respondent
                // before giving up
                timeout, 
            })

        // store the respondent SID in cache so we can
        // end the call if the user end the call
        // this is a HACK, it may need to be stored in DB
        inProgressCallsCache[body.CallSid] = call.sid

        return response.toString()
    },
}

export const answerCallCallback = {
    route: '/answer-call/call-back',
    async main() {
        // this allow the respondent to be connected to the caller 
        // once the respondent pick up the phone
        const response = new VoiceResponse()
        response.dial().queue(queueName)
        return response.toString()
    },
}

export const answerCallWaitMsgSvc = {
    route: '/answer-call/wait-msg',
    async main() {
        // wait url will be responsible for playing the message 
        // and gathering user input while the callers awaits
        const response = new VoiceResponse()
        const gather = response.gather({
            action: url(`/answer-call/record-input`),
            method: 'POST'
        })
        gather.say(`We are connecting you with someone. You can press any digit to end the call.`)
        return response.toString()
    },
}



export const answerCallRecordUserINput = {
    route: '/answer-call/record-input',
    async main(body) {
        // The user has pressed a digit so we may take further actions here
        // and end the call for both caller and respondent
        console.log(`Recorded input`, body.Digits)

        const callingSid = body.CallSid

        const response = new VoiceResponse()
        response.say(`Thank you, we will end the call now.`)
        response.hangup()

            const respondentSid = inProgressCallsCache[callingSid] 
            if (respondentSid) client.calls(respondentSid).update({ status: 'canceled' }).catch(err => console.error(err))

        return response.toString()
    },
}
```

Please let me know if you need further details or converting to express syntax.